# WP website won't accept any new content - need dedicated hosting?

Tags: upgrade, hosting, limit, vps

I can't add any more content to the website. Theme devs said to increase limits on the server (memory_limit, max_input_vars, max_execution_time). We upgraded a package with the host, and tried to manually change these. However I can't do that because it's shared hosting.

Hosting support now suggested to upgrade our account to a cPanel, VPS or Dedicated Server, and move the site.

I never had to do that before, and I'm wondering if they're just trying to upsell, or is it actually necessary to get dedicated hosting? Any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Diane. This site is for questions about software development, so, your question seems out of the scope of this site. You should contact with the support team of your hosting company.

Comment: Have you tried disabling plugins, switching to a default theme, and checking if you can add content then? It sounds like the database may be overloaded which most often has to do with the plugins you're running. But on a decent host (shared, dedicated or otherwise) you should have enough resources to keep adding posts almost indefinitely. You might want to try a database cleanup/optimization plugin and see if that helps. It does sound like you need a new host but I wouldn't stick with the one you have now.

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone. The problem seemed to have been in the chosen hosting provider because they couldn't change some of the settings (memory_limit, max_input_vars, max_execution_time), so we switched to another provider who could.